# Is There a Way to Force a Project Reference to .NET Standard Project to a Specific TargetFramework

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

I am a contributor to a GitHub project, and recently we had some trouble with our [.NET Standard 2.0 project installing correctly into a .NET Framework 4.5 project](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer/issues/160).  The cause of this is that (if I am understanding correctly) [.NET Standard 2.0 supports a minimum .NET Framework of 4.6.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

OK, fair enough.  So we updated the .csproj to create another framework output:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

In our testing project, the supported frameworks are defined as such:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net471;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

However, we are running into a problem with the `net471` build as it seems to be picking up the `net45` framework and not the `netstandard2.0`.  In order to get this working, we are having to set the `TargetFrameworks` of the class library as such:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

This seems excessive as it would seem that `.netstandard2.0` should be the `TargetFramework` that `net471` picks up, rather than the `net45` target.

Is there a way to force a project reference to a particular `TargetFramework`?  I did try the following in our testing project, but it did not seem work:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net471'">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ExtendedXmlSerializer\ExtendedXmlSerializer.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471'">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ExtendedXmlSerializer\ExtendedXmlSerializer.csproj">
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: It is by design for `net471` to pick up `net45`, and that also matches expectation. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @lex-li, since there is a `netstandard2.0` profile, and its minimum is 4.6.1, it would seem that a `net471` profile would select `netstandard2.0` since 4.6.1 is higher than 4.5?  My understanding is that `netstandard2.0` is actually `net461` when bound to a .NET Framework-based application.  So, it would seem that when given a `net471` application, `net461` would take precedence over `net45`.

Comment: that's a wrong assumption. As .NET Standard does not cover all .NET Framework API, you can easily found a NuGet package requiring it's .NET Framework consumers to stick to the .NET Framework specific assemblies. I am maintaining such as NuGet package, so I don't want the current behaviour to be changed in any way.

Comment: the "nearest TFM" selection logic always selects the same framework in a compatible version before falling back to compatible other frameworks. this has been this way before .net standard (e.g. PCLs). For project references, there's still msbuild tricks that can be used (see answer). it really is useful for tests projects in some situations.

Comment: Ahhh... I am with you now.  Even though .netstandard2.0 is technically 4.6.1, it doesn't start with a `net` moniker.  `net45` is the only moniker available so it goes with this first.  There really needs to be a way to configure (or define) a selection strategy.  And by that I mean a little more elegant than hard coding TFM in obscure MSBuld-defined variables. ;)  Anyways, thanks for your help, all!

Comment: Please change the accepted answer. [According to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2280#issuecomment-605316016), Lorenzo's answer is the recommended solution.

Comment: Thank you @NightOwl888 I have done this and the more current solution is now marked as the answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> It does not work. VS 2017 15.5.5. Reference from 4.6.2 MSTest project net462 target of multitarget (net462;netstandard2.0) class library. – SerG Feb 13 at 13:34

It is true, the new way to solve that is this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\multitargeted_lib\multitargeted_lib.csproj">
  <SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=netstandard2.0</SetTargetFramework>
</ProjectReference>
```

Source is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2280#issuecomment-392815466).

Answer (score 31):

Update 2020: The answer suggesting to use `SetTargetFramework` is a better fit, also to not conflict with other settings.

You can change your project reference like this:

```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\ExtendedXmlSerializer\ExtendedXmlSerializer.csproj" 
                    AdditionalProperties="TargetFramework=netstandard2.0" />
```

to force the selection of a specific target framework over the default "get nearest TFM" logic.

Comment: WOOHOO!  Thank you, Martin!  Exactly what I was looking to do.  Works perfectly.  You = hero. :)  Shout out to you here, my man: https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer/commit/14c7ee8c54f505e5f6c10d1a9043dd3edf24c806

Comment: It does not work. VS 2017 15.5.5. Reference from 4.6.2 MSTest project net462 target of multitarget (net462;netstandard2.0) class library.