# Target Framework Resolution Behavior for Multi-Target Project References

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

This question is nearly identical to this one:
[Is There a Way to Force a Project Reference to .NET Standard Project to a Specific TargetFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526219/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-project-reference-to-net-standard-project-to-a-specif) except I am not looking to do anything exotic like force a Framework project to consume a Standard one.

Similar to that question, I have two multi-target projects, a class library which declares:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

And a consuming Unit Test / Console Application project which declares:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

The second project references the first in the usual way:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MultiTargetProject\MultiTargetProject.csproj" />
```

When I build the solution, `GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask` generates the following Warning:

> NU1702 | ProjectReference 'C:\source\SolutionDir\MultiTargetProject\MultiTargetProject.csproj' was resolved using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project.

Now, based on the previous question, I see there is clearly a way to explicitly define which framework to resolve, and used in combination with some conditional property groups, I can successfully resolve Framework-to-Framework and Standard-to-Core.

**My question is:**

Should this be necessary - I had assumed the .NET Core project would resolve the .NET Standard reference? What is the logic for `GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask` anyway? (I have not been able to find any clear documentation on what the behavior should be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you do not have to complicate this issue too much. The truth is that `net standard 2.1` does not support `net core 2.1`.

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

[image]

**Net Standard 2.1** supports at least **Net Core 3.0**.

You only need to change your main project `targetframeworks` to `netcoreapp3.1;net48` or change `targetframeworks` of your lib project to `netstandard2.0;net48` and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. I just try to imagine the product management meetings behind the "naming principles" of a major vs minor version bump: "of course developers will read the docs! there's no possibility for confusion, *at all*"  :)  Looks right, I will accept as soon as I get a chance to verify.

Comment: Well. That is the point. And I have tested it in my side. It is related to the target framework compatibility.